# How can I JMP to relocated code in my MBR?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader, osdev

I'm trying to write an extremely simple MBR to start learning how to write an MBR/Kernel.  This is what I have so far (created from pieces of other MBRs). The binary I get from using nasm and then ld to link is a bit different from just using nasm for both, but that doesn't appear to be the problem.

I first started with `jmp 0:continue` but that appears to jump to `0000:7c22` (or `001d` with nasm alone... i believe i didnt specify that it starts at `7c00`) but im looking to jump to `:7a22` or `:7a1d`, the address of the relocated code.  I tried using just `jmp continue` and then as seen uncommented below, adding the stack pointer to the continue pointer, pushing it and ret. All I get is a blinking cursor when dd'ed to my 1st sector.  Any help is appreciated.

```
                            ; nasm+ld       nasm            comment
global _start
_start:
    xor    cx, cx           ; 6631c9        31c9            Set segment registers to zero
    mov    es, cx           ; 8ec1          8ec1
    mov    ds, cx           ; 8ed9          8ed9
    mov    ss, cx           ; 8ed1          8ed1
    mov    sp, 0x7A00       ; 66bc007a      bc007a          Stack
    mov    di, sp           ; 6689e7        89e7            Bottom of relocation point
    mov    esi, _start      ; be007c0000    66be00000000
    cld                     ; fc            fc
    mov    ch, 1            ; b501          b501            cx = 256
    rep movsw               ; f366a5        f3a5            Copy self to 0:7A00

;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    xor    eax,eax
    mov    ax, sp
    add    ax, continue

    ;jmp    0:continue      ; ea227c00000000    ea1d000000      near JMP to copy of self
                            ; or
    ;jmp    continue        ; (eb00)
    push eax
    ret
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

continue:
    sti                     ; fb            fb

ERROR:
    mov esi, errormsg       ; be3b7c0000 (be36) 66be36000000        Error Message loc
    mov ah, 0x0E            ; b40e          b40e
    mov bx, 7               ; 66bb          bb0700
disp:
    lodsb                   ; ac            ac
    cmp ah, 0x00            ; 80fc00        80fc00
    je end                  ; 7404          7404
    int 10h                 ; cd10          cd10
    jmp disp                ; ebf6          ebf6

end:
    nop                     ; 90            90
    jmp end                 ; ebfd          ebfd            infinte loop

errormsg db 10,'YOU MESSED UP.',13,0

times (0x1b8 - ($-$$)) nop  ; 90            90          Padding

UID db 0xf5,0xbf,0x0f,0x18                                         ;Unique Disk ID

BLANK times 2 db 0

PT1 db 0x80,0x20,0x21,0x00,0x0C,0x50,0x7F,0x01,0x00,0x08,0x00,0x00,0xb0,0x43,0xF9,0x0D ;First Partition Entry
PT2 times 16 db 0                                      ;Second Partition Entry
PT3 times 16 db 0                                      ;Third Partition Entry
PT4 times 16 db 0                                      ;Fourth Partition Entry

BOOTSIG dw 0xAA55                                      ;Boot Signature[/code]
```

Comment: Looks like your linker is producing 32-bit code, which is wrong for a boot sector. (Though I've never heard of `ld` actually inserting size prefixes before the instructions... whole thing looks strange). What are the _actual commands_ you are using to assemble and link? How are you dumping the result in both cases?

Comment: @davmac The linker isn't doing that. It's NASM.  He needs a `BITS 16` directive to make it explicit.

Comment: @RossRidge ok, but the opcodes in the "nasm" column in his comments looks like correct 16-bit code. Of course I don't know where he's actually getting those from.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would think `jmp 0:continue` could possibly do the right thing. How can the assembler or linker know where you've copied the code?

Comment: `nasm -f bin -o mbr.dd mbr.asm` or `nasm -f elf mbr.asm; ld mbr.o -o mbr.bin -Ttext 0x00007C00 --oformat binary` and I just hexdumped the files to get the opcodes

Comment: @davmac NASM chooses a default for BITS based on the object format used. With `elf` it defaults to 32, with `bin` it defaults to 16.

Comment: @Willdorf you can use 32-bit instructions, but the code must be generated in 16-bit mode. (32-bit instructions will be generated with operand size prefixes as appropriate). What you are seeing now is operand size prefixes (66h) where they shouldn't be. (The processor can be in 16-bit or 32-bit mode; in either mode, the 66h prefix will switch to the alternate operand size. The boot sector will be executed in 16-bit mode).

Comment: Okay so the nasm(compile/link) is generating good 16-bit code, but how can I get the code to jump to the new (7axx) address?

Comment: @Willdorf use an appropriate `org` directive, I guess. Or change the `-Ttext 0x00007C00` in your linker command. You're claiming the code is at 0x7C00, and it does exactly what you ask...

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I'm going to post an answer with the updated code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have discovered you can set the origin point to `ORG 0x7A00` for your entire bootloader. That works perfectly well. The code that copies the boot sector to 0x7A00 doesn't rely on any labels that are absolute, just relatives ones. This answer is more of a thought experiment and a different way of approaching it.

What would happen if we wanted to display a string before the copy as an example? What are some possible options?

1. *NASM* allows for the BIN format (`-f bin`) to have sections that take on a [virtual starting point](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html) (origin point) and a physical address (start). This method is too restrictive for how a bootloader is laid out.
2. Use an [*LD* linker script](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html#SEC4) to define the layout of the bootloader.
3. Reorganize code to use an *ORG* (origin point) of 0x0000 and set the segment registers accordingly. See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37379429/3857942) to this question.

This answer focuses on option 2. Explaining how *LD* Linker scripts work is too broad for Stackoverflow. The [*LD* manual](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_toc.html#SEC3) is the best source of information, and it does have examples. The idea is that we allow the bootloader to be laid out inside the linker script. We can set up LMA (Load Memory Address) to specify the memory address where the section will be loaded into memory. The VMA is the origin point for a section. All labels and addresses within a section will be resolved relative to its VMA.

Conveniently we can use a section with a specific LMA to place the boot signature directly into the output file, rather than specify it in the assembly code. We can also define symbols from the linker script that can be accessed from the assembly code using the *NASM* `extern` directive.

One advantage to all this is that you can define sections in your assembly code in any order you want and the linker script will reorder things. You can also link together multiple object files. The object file containing the boot code you want to appear first should be listed first.

The layout of this linker script roughly looks like this:

> ```
> Non-relocatable portion of boot code (boot.text) Relative to an origin of 0x7c00
> Non-relocatable portion of boot data (boot.data)
> --------------------------------------- Word aligned
> Relocatable portion of boot code (rel.text) - Relative to an origin of 0x7a00
> Relocatable portion of boot data (rel.data)
> Relocatable portion of partition data at offset 0x1b8 (partition.data)
> ---------------------------------------
> Boot signature at offset 0x1fe
> ```

A linker script that would layout this boot loader could look something like:

```
ENTRY(_start);
OUTPUT(elf_i386);

SECTIONS
{
    /* Set the base of the main bootloader offsets */
    _bootbase = 0x7c00; /* Where bootloader initially is loaded in memory */
    _relbase  = 0x7a00; /* Address entire bootsector will be copied to
                           This linker script expects it to be word aligned */
    _partoffset = 0x1b8; /* Offset of UID and Partition data */
    _sigoffset  = 0x1fe; /* Offset of the boot signature word */


    /* SUBALIGN(n) in an output section will override the alignment
     * of any input section that is encontered */

    /* This is the boot loader code and data that is expected to run from 0x7c00 */
    .bootinit _bootbase : SUBALIGN(2)
    {
        *(boot.text);
        *(boot.data);
    }

    /* Note that referencing any data in the partition table will
     * only be usable from the code that is in the .bootrel section */

    /* Partition data */
    .partdata _relbase + _partoffset :
        AT(_bootbase + _partoffset) SUBALIGN(0)
    {
        *(partition.data);
    }

    /* Boot signature */
    .bootsig :
        AT(_bootbase + _sigoffset) SUBALIGN(0)
    {
        SHORT(0xaa55);
    }
    /* Length of region to copy in 16-bit words */
    _rel_length = 256;
    /* Address to copy to */
    _rel_start = _relbase; /* Word aligned start address */

    /* Code and data that will expect to run once relocated
     * is placed in this section. Aligned to word boundary.
     * This relocateable code and data will be placed right
     * after the .bootinit section in the output file */
    .bootrel _relbase + SIZEOF(.bootinit) :
        AT(_bootbase + SIZEOF(.bootinit)) SUBALIGN(2)
    {
        *(rel.text);
        *(rel.data);
    }
}
```

A revised copy of your code using this linker script and the symbols defined in it could look like:

```
BITS 16

extern _bootbase
extern _relbase
extern _rel_length
extern _rel_start

section boot.text
                            ; comment
global _start
_start:
    xor    cx, cx           ; Set segment registers to zero
    mov    es, cx
    mov    ds, cx
    mov    ss, cx
    mov    sp, 0x7A00       ; Stack
    cld

.copymsg:
    mov si, copymsg         ; Copy message
    mov ah, 0x0E            ; 0E TTY Output
    mov bx, 7               ; Page number
.dispcopy:
    lodsb                   ; Load next char
    test al, al             ; Compare to zero
    jz .end                 ; If so, end
    int 10h                 ; Display char
    jmp .dispcopy           ; Loop
.end:
    mov    di, _rel_start   ; Beginning of relocation point
    mov    si, _bootbase    ; Original location to copy from
    mov    cx, _rel_length  ; CX = words to copy
    rep movsw               ; Copy self to destination

    jmp    0:rel_entry      ; far JMP to copy of self

section rel.text
rel_entry:
    sti                     ; Enable interrupts

    mov si, successmsg      ; Error Message location
    mov ah, 0x0E            ; 0E TTY Output
    mov bx, 7               ; Page number
.disp:
    lodsb                   ; Load next char
    test al, al             ; Compare to zero
    je .end                 ; If so, end
    int 10h                 ; Display char
    jmp .disp               ; Loop

    cli                     ; Disable interrupts
.end:
    hlt                     ; CPU hlt
    jmp .end                ; infinte loop

section rel.data
successmsg db 10,'Success!',13,0

section boot.data
copymsg db 10,'Before copy!',13,0

section partition.data
UID db 0xf5,0xbf,0x0f,0x18  ;Unique Disk ID

BLANK times 2 db 0

PT1 db 0x80,0x20,0x21,0x00,0x0C,0x50,0x7F,0x01
    db 0x00,0x08,0x00,0x00,0xb0,0x43,0xF9,0x0D
PT2 times 16 db 0
PT3 times 16 db 0
PT4 times 16 db 0
```

As an experiment to make sure that the code in the `boot.text` section could access the data in the `boot.data` I display a string before the copy. I then do a *FAR JMP* to the relocated code. The relocated code displays a success string.

I modified the code to not use the 32-bit registers like *ESI* since you will be executing this code in real mode. I also amended your infinite loop to use the [*HLT*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/HLT.html) instruction.

The code and linker script could be modified to only copy from the start of the relocated data up to the 512th byte, but is beyond the scope of this answer.

---

## A Look at the Disassembly

The `.bootinit` section that has an origin point of 0x7c00 is provided below. This is an *OBJDUMP* snippet of that section (without the data for brevity):

```
Disassembly of section .bootinit:

00007c00 <_start>:
    7c00:       31 c9                   xor    cx,cx
    7c02:       8e c1                   mov    es,cx
    7c04:       8e d9                   mov    ds,cx
    7c06:       8e d1                   mov    ss,cx
    7c08:       bc 00 7a                mov    sp,0x7a00
    7c0b:       fc                      cld

00007c0c <_start.copymsg>:
    7c0c:       be 2e 7c                mov    si,0x7c2e
    7c0f:       b4 0e                   mov    ah,0xe
    7c11:       bb 07 00                mov    bx,0x7

00007c14 <_start.dispcopy>:
    7c14:       ac                      lods   al,BYTE PTR ds:[si]
    7c15:       84 c0                   test   al,al
    7c17:       74 04                   je     7c1d <_start.end>
    7c19:       cd 10                   int    0x10
    7c1b:       eb f7                   jmp    7c14 <_start.dispcopy>

00007c1d <_start.end>:
    7c1d:       bf 00 7a                mov    di,0x7a00
    7c20:       be 00 7c                mov    si,0x7c00
    7c23:       b9 00 01                mov    cx,0x100
    7c26:       f3 a5                   rep movs WORD PTR es:[di],WORD PTR ds:[si]
    7c28:       ea 3e 7a 00 00          jmp    0x0:0x7a3e
```

All the VMA addresses on the left column appear to be properly set relative to the origin point 0x7c00. The *FAR JUMP* (`jmp 0x0:0x7a3e`) also jumped to the location where everything was relocated (copied). A similar abbreviated dump of the `.bootrel` section appears as:

```
Disassembly of section .bootrel:

00007a3d <rel_entry-0x1>:
        ...

00007a3e <rel_entry>:
    7a3e:       fb                      sti
    7a3f:       be 54 7a                mov    si,0x7a54
    7a42:       b4 0e                   mov    ah,0xe
    7a44:       bb 07 00                mov    bx,0x7

00007a47 <rel_entry.disp>:
    7a47:       ac                      lods   al,BYTE PTR ds:[si]
    7a48:       3c 00                   cmp    al,0x0
    7a4a:       74 05                   je     7a51 <rel_entry.end>
    7a4c:       cd 10                   int    0x10
    7a4e:       eb f7                   jmp    7a47 <rel_entry.disp>
    7a50:       fa                      cli

00007a51 <rel_entry.end>:
    7a51:       f4                      hlt
    7a52:       eb fd                   jmp    7a51 <rel_entry.end>
```

The VMA in the left column is relative to the beginning of 0x7A00 which is correct. The instruction `mov si,0x7a54` is an absolute near memory address and it is properly encoded to reference the `successmsg` address (I snipped the data out for brevity so it doesn't appear).

The entries:

```
00007a3d <rel_entry-0x1>:
        ...
```

Are information related to aligning the `.bootrel` section to an even word boundary. With this linker script `rel_entry` will always have an even address.

---

## Compiling and Linking this Bootloader

The easiest way is to use these commands:

```
nasm -f elf32 -o boot.o boot.asm
ld -melf_i386 -Tlinker.ld -o boot.bin --oformat=binary boot.o
```

It should be pointed out that we are using *ELF32* format with *NASM*, not *BIN*. *LD* is then used to create the binary file `boot.bin` which should be a 512 byte image of the boot sector. `linker.ld` is the name of the linker script file.

If you want the convenience of being able to get an object dump then you can use these commands to assemble and link:

```
nasm -f elf32 -o boot.o boot.asm
ld -melf_i386 -Tlinker.ld -o boot.elf boot.o
objcopy -O binary boot.elf boot.bin
```

The difference from the first method is that we don't use `--oformat=binary` option with *LD*. The result will be that an *ELF32* image will be generated and placed in the output file `boot.elf`. We can't use `boot.elf` directly as our boot image, so we use *OBJCOPY* to convert the *ELF32* file to a binary file called `boot.bin`. The usefulness of doing it this way can be seen if we use a command like this to dump the contents and disassembly of the *ELF* file:

```
objdump boot.elf -Mintel -mi8086 -Dx
```

- `-D` option is disassemble all
- `-x` output the headers
- `-mi8086` disassemble as 16-bit 8086 code
- `-Mintel` disassembly should be *INTEL* syntax rather than default *ATT* syntax

Comment: Thank you that is a lot of useful info on linker scripts, compiling, and disassembly!

Answer (score 3):

Compiled and linked using: `nasm -f bin -o mbr.bin mbr.asm`

```
[BITS 16]
ORG 0x00007a00
                            ; opcodes       comment
global _start
_start:
    xor    cx, cx           ; 31c9          Set segment registers to zero
    mov    es, cx           ; 8ec1
    mov    ds, cx           ; 8ed9
    mov    ss, cx           ; 8ed1
    mov    sp, 0x7A00       ; bc007a        Stack
    mov    di, sp           ; 89e7          Bottom of relocation point
    mov    esi, 0x00007C00  ; 66be007c0000  Original location
    cld                     ; fc
    mov    ch, 1            ; b501          CX = 256
    rep movsw               ; f3a5          Copy self to 0:7A00
    jmp    0:continue       ; ea1d7a0000    near JMP to copy of self

continue:
    sti                     ; fb

ERROR:
    mov esi, errormsg       ; 66be357a0000  Error Message location
    mov ah, 0x0E            ; b40e          0E TTY Output
    mov bx, 7               ; bb0700        Page number
disp:
    lodsb                   ; ac            Load next char
    cmp al, 0x00            ; 3c00          Compare to zero
    je end                  ; 7404          If so, end
    int 10h                 ; cd10          Display char
    jmp disp                ; ebf6          Loop

end:
    nop                     ; 90            Do Nothing
    jmp end                 ; ebfd          infinte loop

errormsg db 10,'YOU MESSED UP!',13,0

times (0x1b8 - ($-$$)) nop  ; 90909090...   Padding

UID db 0xf5,0xbf,0x0f,0x18  ;Unique Disk ID

BLANK times 2 db 0

PT1 db 0x80,0x20,0x21,0x00,0x0C,0x50,0x7F,0x01
PT1more db 0x00,0x08,0x00,0x00,0xb0,0x43,0xF9,0x0D
PT2 times 16 db 0
PT3 times 16 db 0
PT4 times 16 db 0

BOOTSIG dw 0xAA55           ;Boot Signature
```

Output of `hexdump -C mbr.bin`:

```
00000000  31 c9 8e c1 8e d9 8e d1  bc 00 7a 89 e7 66 be 00  |1.........z..f..|
00000010  7c 00 00 fc b5 01 f3 a5  ea 1d 7a 00 00 fb 66 be  ||.........z...f.|
00000020  35 7a 00 00 b4 0e bb 07  00 ac 3c 00 74 04 cd 10  |5z........<.t...|
00000030  eb f7 90 eb fd 0a 59 4f  55 20 4d 45 53 53 45 44  |......YOU MESSED|
00000040  20 55 50 21 0d 00 90 90  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  | UP!............|
00000050  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  |................|
*
000001b0  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  f5 bf 0f 18 00 00 80 20  |............... |
000001c0  21 00 0c 50 7f 01 00 08  00 00 b0 43 f9 0d 00 00  |!..P.......C....|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200
```

Comment: There's no reason to use ESI over SI, since the 16-bit MOVSW and LODSB instructions only use the 16-bit SI register.

Comment: Why are you setting `ORG` to `0x7a00`. This should be `0x7c00`.

Comment: Additionally, you can set `sp` to `0x7c00` as well. Since the stack grows down there is really no reason not to. You don't need to put a trap between them.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer : He has set it to 0x7a00 because the code that does the copy is relocatable (doesn't matter what the org is at that point). Once the copy is done the rest of his code is now copied to 0x7a00 so it should run as expected. It is rather unorthodox but in this case it should work.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer : regarding his _SP_ . Since he has copied the 512 bytes of the bootloader from 0x7c00 to 0x7a00 it appears he has chosen to place the stack just below the destination where he copied - which seems reasonable. I am guessing he is building a chain loader.

Comment: You're right, @MichaelPetch - Honestly, I didn't look further than the odd ORG and SP adjustments.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative for relocating an MBR/bootloader that doesn't involve a linker script but allows *ALL* the code and data in the bootloader to be relocated anywhere that a segment:offset pair = segment:0x0000. This doesn't limit the bootloader from being copied within the 64kb of memory. This involves using some segment math and a few minor alterations to the code. I'm going to use your original code with some cleanup plus the instructions I added in my first answer that prints a string before the *JMP*.

Remember that in x86 [real mode segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086#Segmentation) a physical address is determined by the contents of a segment register and the offset. The calculation is as follows:

```
Physical address = (segment << 4) + offset
```

In the case of bootloaders many people place 0x0000 into *DS* and *ES*, which you did in your code. Your original code used `ORG 0x7c00` (which is effectively the offset). When you take the segment and offset and compute the physical address you get:

```
Physical address = (0x0000 << 4) + 0x7c00 = 0x07c00
```

0x07c00 is the physical address of the bootloader that was placed in memory by the BIOS. However there is generally more than one way to express a single physical address as a segment:offset pair.

As an example if we use a segment of 0x07c0 and an ORG(offset) of 0x0000 we find that the equation yields:

```
Physical address = (0x07c0 << 4) + 0x0000 = 0x07c00
```

What if set up the original segment registers to 0x07c0 and use an `ORG 0x0000` directive within the bootloader. Would that work? Yes, it would. The linker and *NASM* really have no concept of how the user sets the segment registers. When *NASM* creates references to *NEAR* absolute addresses, it assumes that the segments will be set up appropriately by the developer at run-time.

If we use `ORG 0x0000`, then to do the copy from the 0x7c00 to 0x7a00 we can place 0x07c0 into *DS* and *SI* to 0 (0x07c0:0x0000). We can set *ES* to 0x07a0 and *DI* to 0 (0x07a0:0x0000). *CX* would be set to 256 (we'll copy words). This would copy 512 bytes of memory from physical address 0x07c00 to 0x07a00. Once the entire bootloader is copied we then use *FAR JMP* to set *CS* to segment specified in the jump and set the instruction pointer (IP) to the offset of the label.

Once we jump to the memory (region starting at physical address 0x7a00) where the bootloader was copied, we set up the segment registers accordingly. So in our case we'd set the registers *DS* and *ES* after the jump to 0x07a0. This should allow all the bootloader code and data to run as expected in the new location.

The following is code that would do something similar as to what has been suggested above:

```
BITS 16
ORG 0x0000

global _start
_start:
    xor    bp, bp           
    mov    ss, bp           ; Set SS segment register to zero
    mov    sp, 0x7A00       ; Set stack to SS:SP=0x0000:0x7A00
    mov    dx, 0x07C0
    mov    ds, dx           ; DS = 0x07C0 - Segment:Offset = 0x07c0:0x0000 = 0x07C00
    sub    dx, 0x20         ; DX = 0x07C0-0x20=0x07A0
    mov    es, dx           ; ES = 0x07A0 - Segment:Offset = 0x07a0:0x0000 = 0x07A00
    cld

    ; Print message before the copy
    mov si, copymsg         ; Copy message (DS:[copymsg])
    call outputstr

    ; Copy 256 words of memory from 0x07c00 to 0x07a00
    mov    di, bp           ; Destination is ES:DI = 0x07a0:0x0000 = 0x07a00
    mov    si, bp           ; Source is DS:SI = 0x07c0:0x0000 = 0x07c00
    mov    cx, 256          ; CX = 256 words to copy
    rep movsw               ; Copy self to destination

    jmp    0x07A0:rel_entry
                            ; far JMP jumps to phys address 0x07a00, sets
                            ; CS = 0x07A0 and IP = rel_entry.

rel_entry:
    sti                     ; Enable interrupts
    mov    ds, dx           ; DS=ES=0x07A0
                            ; ES already 0x07A0 before the jump, no need to set again
.success:
    ; Print the "Success!" message
    mov si, successmsg      ; Success Message location (DS:[successmsg])
    call outputstr

    cli                     ; Disable interrupts
.end:
    hlt                     ; CPU hlt
    jmp .end                ; infinite loop

; Function: outputstr
; Inputs:
;    SI = address of string
; Outputs:
;    None
; Registers destroyed:
;    AX, BX, SI
;
outputstr:
    mov ah, 0x0E            ; 0E TTY Output
    mov bx, 7               ; Page number
.disp:
    lodsb                   ; Load next char from DS:[SI], SI+=2
    test al, al             ; Compare to zero
    je .end                 ; If so, end
    int 0x10                ; Display char
    jmp .disp               ; Loop
.end:
    ret

successmsg db 10,'Success!',13,0
copymsg db 10,'Before copy!',13,0

times (0x1b8 - ($-$$)) db 0x00 ; Padding

UID     db 0xf5,0xbf,0x0f,0x18 ; Unique Disk ID
BLANK   times 2 db 0
PT1     db 0x80,0x20,0x21,0x00,0x0C,0x50,0x7F,0x01
PT1more db 0x00,0x08,0x00,0x00,0xb0,0x43,0xF9,0x0D
PT2     times 16 db 0
PT3     times 16 db 0
PT4     times 16 db 0

BOOTSIG dw 0xAA55              ;Boot Signature
```

This bootloader calls a function `outputstr` to display messages to the console both in the code before the copy, and after the jump to the relocated code. This works because in both instances all the labels are still at the same offset, only the segment changed.

The bootloader above could be assembled with a command like:

```
nasm -f bin boot.bin boot.asm
```